# Authentication Issue when Deploying ASP.NET Core 7 API with MongoDB on Azure App Services

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, mongodb-atlas

I'm developing an API using ASP.NET Core 7 with MongoDB. I've set up a database on MongoDB Atlas and I'm using the connection string to access my database through the API. Locally, everything works as expected, and I can also connect to my database using MongoDB Compass.

However, when I deployed my API on Azure App Services and try to make a request to my API, I encounter the following error:

> Erro ao ler usuários: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-00.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-00.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
> ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
> ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions, SelectClientCertificate clientCertificateSelectionCallback)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1718870Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1718873Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-01.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-01.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
> ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
> ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions, SelectClientCertificate clientCertificateSelectionCallback)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1794022Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1794023Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-02.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ac-qh7znw4-shard-00-02.v0kzanp.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
> ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
> ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount) at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions, SelectClientCertificate clientCertificateSelectionCallback)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.SslStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1893947Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-11-09T19:10:01.1893949Z" }] }.

Here is my connection string and implementation:

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://myuser:password@host/database?authSource=admin",
    "DatabaseName": "Database",
    "Collections": {
      "Usuarios": "Usuarios",
      "Imoveis": "Imoveis",
      "Imagens": "Imagens",
      "Avatares": "Avatares"
    }
  },
```

```
namespace IMobi.Cofigurations;
public class MongoDbSettings : IMongoDbSettings
{
  public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public string CollectionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

```
builder.Services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
```

This appears to be an authentication issue with the database, but I'm struggling to comprehend the underlying reasons causing this error. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.